# Python: check for last html tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to know if it is possible to check for the last html tag in a beautifulsoup object. Here is the code.

```
try:
    f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.taylor-enviro.com' + link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)

if len(soup.find_all("td",{"class":"pages"})) > 0:
    print('pages true')
    pagelinkrow = soup.find("td",{"class":"pages"})
    if len(pagelinkrow.find_all("li")) > 0:
        print('litrue')
        for pagelinkrow1 in pagelinkrow.findAll('li'):
            try:
                print('intry')
                pagelink = pagelinkrow1.a['href']
                if pagelink not in linklist:
                    linklist.append(pagelink)
                    print (pagelink)
                return pagelink

                found = 'done'
            except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
```

I would like to check for last 'li'.

Answer (score 1):

`pagelinkrow.find_all("li")` returns an array of `li` elements. You can get the last item of that array by using index `-1`:

```
pagelinkrow.find_all("li")[-1]
```